# Integral of the difference between the Empirical Cumulative Distribution and True Distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Please provide alternative suggestions with detailed steps to simplify this expression and well known results with references that might apply in this case.

If there are any mistakes, please let me know.

## Expression,

$$
c=\int_{0}^{K}\left\{ F_{n}\left(t\right)-F\left(t\right)\right\} dt
$$

Here, $K>0$ , $F_{n}\left(t\right)$ is the empirical cumulative distribution function and $F\left(t\right)$ is the true cumulative distribution function.

## Steps Tried,

$$
\left|c\right|\leq\int_{0}^{K}\left|\left\{ F_{n}\left(t\right)-F\left(t\right)\right\} \right|dt
$$
$$
\left|c\right|\leq \sup_{{x\in{\mathbb{R}}}}\left|\left\{ F_{n}\left(x\right)-F\left(x\right)\right\} \right|\int_{0}^{K}dt
$$
$$
\left|c\right|\leq \sup_{{x\in{\mathbb{R}}}}\left|\left\{ F_{n}\left(x\right)-F\left(x\right)\right\} \right|K
$$

$$
\frac{1}{K}\left|c\right|\leq \sup_{{x\in{\mathbb{R}}}}\left|\left\{ F_{n}\left(x\right)-F\left(x\right)\right\} \right|
$$

Using the well known Kolmogorov-Smirnov / Dvoretzky, Kiefer and Wolfowitz results,

$$
\Pr{\Bigl(}\sup_{{x\in{\mathbb{R}}}}|F_{n}(x)-F(x)|<\varepsilon{\Bigr)}\geq1-2e^{{-2n\varepsilon^{2}}}\qquad{\text{for every }}\varepsilon>0
$$

$$
\Pr{\Bigl(}\frac{1}{K}\left|c\right|<\varepsilon{\Bigr)}\geq1-2e^{{-2n\left(\varepsilon\right)^{2}}}\qquad{\text{for every }}\varepsilon>0
$$

$$
\Pr{\Bigl(}|c|<K\varepsilon{\Bigr)}\geq1-2e^{{-2n\left(\varepsilon\right)^{2}}}\qquad{\text{for every }}\varepsilon>0
$$

Any suggestions on how to improve the bound because this seems to be a very similar bound as the Dvoretzky, Kiefer and Wolfowitz inequality.

$$
\Pr{\Bigl(}\left|c\right|<\delta{\Bigr)}\geq1-2e^{{-2n\left(\frac{\delta}{K}\right)^{2}}}\qquad{\text{for every }}\delta>0
$$
Putting, $\delta=\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{n}}$, simplifying further and taking the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$,

$$
\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\Pr{\Bigl(}\left|c\right|<\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{n}}{\Bigr)}\geq1-2e^{{-2\left(\frac{\lambda}{K}\right)^{2}}}\qquad{\text{for every }}\lambda>0
$$

Comment: Can't you take $\varepsilon = \frac{\delta}{K}$?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris, thanks for this suggestion. I believe I just did that just a few minutes before your comment. Please let me know if you are seeing this updated result.

Comment: Yes, I see it.  Thanks!

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris, I believe there is a scope to improve the bounds further; but unable to get my head around it and perhaps my level of familiarity with these techniques is limited.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant to say that  $F_n$ was the empirical cumulative distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, drawn independently from the distribution $F$.  Then by integration by parts, your $$c = EY - \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i,$$ where $Y_i = X_i $ if $X_i\le K$ and $Y_i=0$ otherwise.

If $F$ has a finite second moment you can, for given $K$, work out the mean and variance of the $Y_i$ and apply the central limit theorem to find the limiting distribution for $c$.  In non-trivial cases, the answer depends on $K$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Please note, we can obtain a bound as mentioned above in the steps tried. Please see if that looks correct or any issues you see with that.

Comment: On rereading the original post it is not clear to me what the problem is, exactly, and what  the assumptions on $F$ are.  What I did way exhibit your $c$ as an i.i.d. sum, to which you can apply Chernoff's inequality to get bounds of the form you seem to want.

Comment: please note any and all simplifications would be of interest including both the finite sample and asymptotic behaviour. There are no assumptions regarding $F$. It is any general distribution. As I understand, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov / Dvoretzky, Kiefer and Wolfowitz results can be applied for any general distributions.